# How to implement a generic calculator class

Tags: java, generics

An instructor recently set the task of coding a small calculator class for integers and doubles. As worded the assignment is covered by the following:

```
public final class Calculator {

    public int add(int augend, int addend) { return augend + addend; }
    public double add(double augend, double addend) { return augend + addend; }

    public int subtract(int minuend, int subtrahend) { return minuend - subtrahend; }
    public double subtract(double minuend, double subtrahend) { return minuend - subtrahend; }

    public int divide(int dividend, int divisor) { return dividend / divisor; }
    public double divide(double dividend, double divisor) { return dividend / divisor; }

    public int multiply(int multiplicand, int multiplier) { return multiplicand * multiplier; }
    public double multiply(double multiplicand, double multiplier) { return multiplicand * multiplier; }
}
```

I am wondering though, given that the methods are functionally the same if the
duplication of the functionality could be removed somehow by the use of generics?

I have tried a couple of routes to make this happen, the latest is to make the entire class generic as follows, but keep getting stuck where it comes to actually applying the mathematical operations to the variables

```
public class Calculator<T extends Number> {
    public T add(T augend, T addend) {
        // addition is the same for any number type
        return augend + addend; // "operator '+' cannot be applied to 'T','T'"
    }
    // etc...
}
```

The error message, or a variant thereof, comes into play with whichever method I try... Is there a better way to do this? (with or without generics)

Comment: depends on how generic would the calculator be, would you like `Animal` class to be able to `add` using your `Calculator`?

Comment: Well, you could always try to convert your input to `BigDecimal` which should be able to hold about every value your calculator could produce and provides methods like `add()` etc. All the rest - if really needed - would be a conversion layer.

Comment: @nullpointer my bad, I forgot the boundary on the generic - it doesn't really matter if someone tries to add animals I guess - but ideally it should be for number types only if possible

Comment: you could do `Double.valueOf(augend.doubleValue() + addend.doubleValue())`

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately the return type is then incompatible, required T, found Double. Ideally the functions would return a type matching what is specified for T - not sure this is possible though. If the methods return Double though, the `Double.valueOf()` appears unneeded.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher I'd not recommend using `double` in a calculator. Try something like `116.0 / 7.0 * 7.0` (which should return 116.0 but it won't).

Comment: @Toby, the methods doesn't and cannot return T. for instance, imagine `divide( 1, 2). `

Comment: @SharonBenAsher `divide(1, 2)` for `T` of `Integer` should be `0`, just like `int a = 1 / 2` normally is, no? Maybe I'm being really dense here >.<

Comment: the Number class does not support arithmetic operations so if you want something generic you might need to define an interface with methods for each operation, then some implementations for each data type (Integer, Float, ...) and make calculator generic based on the defined interface, but this will not remove the redundancy it will only structure it differently

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can apply operators on Type T. Since during compilation this will get replaced with the object in case of unbounded Type and with the first bound in case of bounded type. Refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html. In the below code, it would get replaced with Number but Number doesn't work with operators.
You can create an generic interface like this :

```
interface Calc<T extends Number>{
   T add(T a, T b);
}
```

Now create Concrete Classes for Integer and Doubles

```
class IntegerCalc implements Calc<Integer>{
    @Override
    public Integer add(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return a+b;
    }
}

class DoubleCalc implements Calc<Double>{
    @Override
    public Double add(Double a, Double b) {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did it fine! Pretty simple and reliable code. Good Job.

***P.S.** Think about that generics work with `Object`, and `Integer` and `int` is not absolutely the same thing. If you can work with a simple type, you should do it and avoid wrappers.*